# API and Threads taking longer than expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, api

I'm trying to do some pull some data with an API using threads since each query takes about 5 seconds when done by itself on Postman. I'm trying to pull about 500 queries. I have 10 threads going at the same time, but each thread seems to take about 20+ seconds and I'm not sure why. It's not very CPU intensive, and I can't see where the bottleneck is.

```
List<PullEncompassThread> puller = new List<PullEncompassThread>();
// class that stores two lists pipeLine is the original List loan list is what the result gets stored into
twoList lists = new twoList();
lists.guidList = pipeLine;
lists.loanList = new List<LoanInfo>();

List<Thread> pullerThreads = new List<Thread>();

int numBots = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < numBots; i++)
{
    puller.Add(new PullEncompassThread(currToken, i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < numBots; i++)
{
    pullerThreads.Add(new Thread(new 
    ParameterizedThreadStart(puller[i].ThreadProc)));
}

for (int i = 0; i < numBots; i++)
{
    pullerThreads[i].Start(lists);
    Console.WriteLine("Bot number " + i + " started");
}

for (int i = 0; i < numBots; i++)
{
    pullerThreads[i].Join();
}
```

Below is the code for the thread. Since they are all sharing the same List I locked it when they access it just to prevent race conditions. Is that what is slowing everything down?

```
public class PullEncompassThread
    {
        public Token access;
        public int botNum;

        public PullEncompassThread(Token key, int num)
        {
            access = key;
            botNum = num;
        }

        public void ThreadProc(object lists)
        {
            while (((twoList)lists).guidList.Count != 0)
            {
                GUID tempGUID;
                lock (((twoList)lists).guidList)
                {
                    tempGUID = ((twoList)lists).guidList[0];
                    ((twoList)lists).guidList.Remove(((twoList)lists).guidList[0]);
                }

//api get and store

                var client = new RestClient("https://api.elliemae.com/encompass/v1/loans/" + tempGUID.loanGuid);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("postman-token", //removed for security);
                request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                request.AddHeader("authorization", "//removed for security");
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                LoanInfo temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoanInfo>(response.Content);
                lock (((twoList)lists).loanList)
                {
                    ((twoList)lists).loanList.Add(temp);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Bot " + botNum + " Got loan " + temp.loanIdNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you test your code by setting a larger value to `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` (by default it is 2)

Comment: Unrelated to speed, but you should also check the count of guidList inside the lock(). Race condition means you will throw an exception as multiple threads try to take the last item.

Comment: I guess you are using http://restsharp.org/? If so, then another possible approach is to use async instead of sync Execute. Like they suggest: client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});

Comment: The first thing you should ask yourself is why each request is taking 5 seconds. That seems unreasonable. Also, consider using `BlockingCollection` instead of `List` for your `guidList`. And, yes, be sure to set your `DefaultConnectionLimit` to 10 (or whatever number of threads you're using). Otherwise, runtime throttle the number of concurrent requests you can make to the same host.

Comment: I think this is exactly it! Thank you so much! Specificly the DefaultConnectionLimit. I'll look into the other things too, thank you very much.